# Is SageMaker multi-node Spot-enabled GPU training an anti-pattern?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, spot-instances, amz-sagemaker-distributed-training

Is it an anti-pattern to do multi-node Spot-enabled distributed GPU training on SageMaker?

I'm afraid that several issues will slow things down or even make them infeasible:

- the interruption detection lag
- the increased probability of interruption (N instances)
- the need to re-download data at every interruption
- the need start/stop whole clusters instead of just replacing interrupted nodes
- the fact that Sagemaker doesn' support variable size cluster

Additionally EC2-Spot documentation deters users from using Spot in multi-node workflows where nodes are tightly coupled (which is the case in data-parallel and model-parallel training) ***"Spot Instances are not suitable for workloads that are inflexible, stateful, fault-intolerant, or tightly coupled between instance nodes."***

Anybody here have experience doing Spot-enabled distributed GPU training on SageMaker happily?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that Spot training works well when the **instance type** you need, in the **region** you need, has enough free capacity, at a particular **time.** Otherwise you won't be able to start the job, or get too frequent interruptions.

Why not just try it for yourself? Once you have a working on-demand training job, you can [enable spot training](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-managed-spot-training.html) by adding 3 relevant parameters to the job's Estimator definition, and implement checkpoint save/load (good to have anyway).  Then if it works well, great! If not, switch back.